# React -Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm-package

Trying to build a react otp component to publish it on npm. Getting this warning on using useState hook while testing the component in a test react app using npm link.

```
import React, { FC, useState } from "react";
interface Props {
  numInputs: number;
}

const OtpInput: FC<Props> = ({ numInputs }): JSX.Element => {
  const [otp, setOtp] = useState(new Array(numInputs || 4).fill(""));

  return (
    <div>
      {otp.map((_, index) => {
        return (
          <React.Fragment key={index}>
            <input type="number" />
          </React.Fragment>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default OtpInput;
```

Warning while testing the component:

```
Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.
This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem. 
    at OtpInput (http://localhost:3000/main.f021bb100c5d3bb39209.hot-update.js:22:76)
    at header
    at div
    at App
```

Tried removing react and react-dom from dev dependencies(both 18.2.0) and only having them as peer dependency as suggested in some other similar questions. But it didn't work.
However if i remove the useState hook and just render some jsx component, it works fine.
Can anyone please explain why am I getting this error?

Edit:
As suggested by @AdamThomas
Ran `npm list react`  got this

```
├─┬ @testing-library/react@13.4.0
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ react-dom@18.2.0
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ react-otp-input-component@1.0.0 -> ./../react-otp-input-component
│ ├─┬ react-dom@18.2.0
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ └── react@18.2.0
├─┬ react-scripts@5.0.1
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
└── react@18.2.0
```

`npm list react-dom` returned

```
├─┬ @testing-library/react@13.4.0
│ └── react-dom@18.2.0 deduped
├── react-dom@18.2.0
└─┬ react-otp-input-component@1.0.0 -> ./../react-otp-input-component
  └── react-dom@18.2.0
```

Comment: Making it a peer dependency is correct. After you did so, I recommend you revert any changes that were previously made to your lockfile, nuke node_modules and install deps again. Probably youve still got 2 stale copies lying around. Are you using NPM CLI or yarn? Also, they need removing from your libs package.json, not your test app -- though you probs already did this

Comment: @AdamThomas I'm using NPM CLI and ran `npm install` after making the change. Still it didn't work

Comment: In your app package, try `npm list react` and also `npm list react-dom` and report back the results in the original question.

Comment: @AdamThomas updated results in the question

Comment: Do you happen to be using `npm link` at all?

Comment: @AdamThomas Sorry, I misunderstood and ran those commands in the component I was building. Updated the question now

Comment: I see you are using symlinks, thats the issue. When you symlink, the library component will use its copy of react, and not your app one. Even if its same version, it does not matter, as the way node require works is such that a copy of it is instantiated. What build tool do you use?

Comment: @AdamThomas I'm using typescript compiler to build the library component

Comment: Added updated answer

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, easiest fix is to stop using `npm link`. First `npm unlink react-otp-input-component` in your app.

Then, instead of linking, [define a `file:` URI in your App package json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#local-paths) that points towards the file location of the `react-otp-input-component`.

Run `npm install` in your app. When you make changes to `react-otp-input-component`, you will need to run npm install again in your app.

Unfortunately, symlinks dont play nice with node require strategy...but there are build-tooling specific workarounds.

Alternatives include configuring an alias in your build tooling such that it forces it to use the copy of React in your app package, or using something like yarn portals.

If using TSC, in `tsconfig` of your app:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "react/*": ["node_modules/react/*"],
      "react-dom/*": ["node_modules/react-dom/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

This will allow you to keep using symlinks.

The reason symlinking doesnt work by default is node and build tooling on top of it will look upwards from the current file till it hits a copy of react. Because symlinking is linking 2 completely separate logical dependency trees with their own `node_modules`, when you import react from the lib, this is the copy that is held by the lib. When you import from the app, this is the copy that is held by the app. When doing a file URI install, the lib is copied into your app node_modules so it uses the same one.

Even if its same version, 2 copies get instantiated if they are in a different place on the filesystem, which causes the error. React relies on 1 instantiation since it is a stateful framework (it stores references to the hooks). This is why not using hooks makes it work. When you *do* use them, the state of those hooks is spread across 2 copies of react, and it gets out of sync.

Comment: Tried both - adding paths and baseUrl in tsconfig of my test app and unlinking and specifying a local path (ran `npm install` again). Getting the same error

Comment: Eek! Well that is odd. Could you update the latest `npm list react` and `npm list react-dom` after trying the file uri so i can validate? Make sure the link in the output is definitely gone. After, id recommend deleting `node_modules`, before trying` npm install` again also. With this amount of change, sometimes you get orphans hanging around.

Comment: Updated it in the question

Comment: Your package is still symlinked unfortunately. As above, make you completely delete node_modules -- that is important. Then put the `file:` uri back in, and npm install.

Comment: `react-otp-input-component@1.0.0 -> ./../react-otp-input-component` indicates theres a link present

Comment: Its easier to just nuke node_modules

Comment: When I specify the local path, its getting symlinked even when I have unlinked the package

Comment: May be I'll try using storybook for this

Comment: Ah...maybe this is something NPM does. I use yarn so could be a diff behaviour. One sec while i research

Comment: Actually I bet npm list output works diff to yarn :(. Maybe that doesnt indicate symlink...damn.

Comment: You can have a look by using your OS file explorer and going into the app node_modules and checking if the lib is copied in their or a symlink.

Comment: Its symlinked. I'll just use storybook to test the library component i'm building.
Thank you for helping me.

Comment: I know what is is :D. You have to run exactly  `npm unlink react-otp-input-component ` first in the app directory BUT THEN run `npm unlink` (no args) in the lib directory. *then* `npm install` in the app directory.

Comment: Sorry refresh that comment have edited. But yeh alls it is is the link is in your global npm store. Actually, even with storybook, its gonna relink it and cause you problems unless you remove it from the link registry.

Comment: Tried that and it too didn't work. Fortunately I'm able to test the component using storybook